# Trying to install Copperhead OS on Nexus 6P

Tags: adb

I want to install CopperheadOS on my Nexus 6P. They have installation instructions here: https://copperhead.co/android/docs/install

Unfortunately, I'm already stuck at the beginning. The installation instructions say that I need to extract the factory images and flash them. Unfortunately when I try to flash them, as soon as it reaches the system partition it returns the following error:

sending 'system' (1174469 KB)...
FAILED (remote: data too large)

I am now unable to boot the phone at all, and stuck in the bootloader. What can I do?

Comment: Revert back to stock firmware, if you can reboot to download mode. It obvious the rom isn't compatible with your phone.

Comment: Make sure you are downloading the correct image for your phone.

Comment: Easy instructions are on Encrypt the planet: https://encrypt-the-planet.com/easily-install-the-copperhead-os-or-stock-google-os-on-your-nexus-5x-or-nexus-6p/

Answer (score -2):

wrong fastboot!

1st i used android-tools-adb and android-tools-fastboot from ubuntu -- didn't work - same error

following the instructions https://copperhead.co/android/docs/install - it worked

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. So could you please [edit] your post and include the basic steps?